# python: handling an array of XML items with element tree preferably "merge"

Tags: python, arrays, xml, elementtree

I have an array called projectDet[]. It contains about 350 items.

**EACH** item in the array is xml information (single item below). The xml for each item is the same format but different id's and values. 
What I'd prefer is to have all of these into one big XML variable that I can pull Elements out of using element tree. Right now I don't know how to use Element tree to go through 300 items in an array.

I have code that checks a different set of XML for the ID and then if the ID in XML data A matches the ID in xml data B, I take "billable hours" out and add it to a final CSV row that matches the id. This works with other XML that ISN'T in an array. So I feel like the easiest way is to use the code I have that works, but I'd need to somehow "merge" all of these entries into one variable that I can pipe into my existing functions.

So is there a way to loop through this array and merge each item together in one xml. They'll all have the same tree structure.. i.e root/team_member/item and root/tasks/item

Thanks for any advice.

```
<root>
<team_members type="list">
    <item type="dict">
        <id>1137</id>
        <cost_rate type="float">76.0</cost_rate>
        <budget_spent_percentage type="null" />
        <projected_hours type="float">0.0</projected_hours>
        <user_id type="int">1351480</user_id>
        <total_hours type="float">0.0</total_hours>
        <name>Bob R</name>
        <budget_left type="null" />
    </item>
    <item type="dict">
        <id>1137</id>
        <cost_rate type="null" />
        <budget_spent_percentage type="null" />
        <projected_hours type="float">2072.0</projected_hours>
        <user_id type="null" />
        <total_hours type="float">0.0</total_hours>
        <name>Samm</name>
        <budget_left type="null" />
    </item>
</team_members>
<nonbillable_detailed_report_url type="str">/reports/detailed/any</nonbillable_detailed_report_url>
<detailed_report_url type="str">/reports/any</detailed_report_url>
<billable_detailed_report_url type="str">/reports/any</billable_detailed_report_url>
<tasks type="list">
    <item type="dict">
        <id>1137</id>
        <budget_left type="null" />
        <budget_spent_percentage type="null" />
        <billed_rate type="float">0.0</billed_rate>
        <over_budget type="null" />
    </item>
    <item type="dict">
        <id>1137</id>
        <budget_left type="null" />
        <budget_spent_percentage type="null" />
        <billed_rate type="float">0.0</billed_rate>
        <over_budget type="null" />
    </item>
    <item type="dict">
        <id>1137</id>
        <budget_left type="null" />
        <budget_spent_percentage type="null" />
        <billed_rate type="float">0.0</billed_rate>
        <over_budget type="null" />
        <total_hours type="float">0.0</total_hours>
        <budget type="null" />
    </item>
    <item type="dict">
        <id>1137</id>
        <budget_left type="null" />
        <budget_spent_percentage type="null" />
        <billed_rate type="float">0.0</billed_rate>
        <over_budget type="null" />
        <total_hours type="float">0.0</total_hours>
        <budget type="null" />
    </item>
    <item type="dict">
        <id>1137</id>
        <budget_left type="null" />
        <budget_spent_percentage type="null" />
        <billed_rate type="float">0.0</billed_rate>
        <over_budget type="null" />
        <total_hours type="float">0.0</total_hours>
        <budget type="null" />
    </item>
    <item type="dict">
        <id>1137</id>
        <budget_left type="null" />
        <budget_spent_percentage type="null" />
        <billed_rate type="float">0.0</billed_rate>
        <over_budget type="null" />
        <total_hours type="float">0.0</total_hours>
        <budget type="null" />
    </item>
 </tasks>
</root>
```

Comment: Is it a numpy array or a list `[]`?

Comment: @Parfait hello again! I created it by doing  projectDet = [ ]    so I guess thats a list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using [`append()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.append) to append all children of the `<root>` iteratively across the list. But initially capture the first full element of `<root>` and then append thereafter:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

cnt = 1
for i in projectDet:
    if cnt == 1:
        main = ET.fromstring(i)

    else:
        team = ET.fromstring(i).findall('.//team_members')
        main.append(team[0])        
        nonbill = ET.fromstring(i).findall('.//nonbillable_detailed_report_url')
        main.append(nonbill[0])
        detrpt = ET.fromstring(i).findall('.//detailed_report_url')
        main.append(detrpt[0])                                          
        bill = ET.fromstring(i).findall('.//billable_detailed_report_url')
        main.append(bill[0])
        task = ET.fromstring(i).findall('.//tasks')
        main.append(task[0])

    cnt+=1

# OUTPUT LARGE XML (main OBJ)
print(ET.tostring(main).decode("UTF-8"))
```